# Reading a file line by line in python and using in for loop python

Tags: python, readfile

Problem: When I run this program with selenium webdriver using "f.readline" the program prints the first password from my password list. Once it loops it repeats the first password again. In contrast, when I attempt "f.readlines"a password does not transfer to the website. Goal: I am trying to get the program to attempt the next password every time the program loops. My password file contains only one password per line. Help is appreciated.

```
 with open('rockyou.txt', 'r') as f:
    passwords = f.readlines()
 for line in passwords:
    password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rcmloginpwd"]')
    password.send_keys(passwords)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in the whole object each loop.  Your last line just needs adjusting I think

```
 with open('rockyou.txt', 'r') as f:
    passwords = f.readlines()
 for line in passwords:
    password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rcmloginpwd"]')
    password.send_keys(line)
```